# Expect script does not work with multiple password requests

Tags: expect

I'm trying to execute a perl script to connect to linux hosts generate a snap and then I need to SCP this snap to my local server. So I have to put password 2 times 1 - to login on the servers and 2 - to SCP the file previously generated.
The problem is, my expect script is only working for the first password, would anyone have any idea?

```
[linuxserver]$ ./mul.sh
spawn perl perlscript.pl
Cleaning up /tmp/logs
Getting logs from server 9.x.x.x using snap
Password:  <------ THIS ITERATION WORKS FINE WITH EXPECT
Password:  <------ THE 2nd ITERATION DOES NOT WORK AND I HAVE TO ADD THE PASSWORD MANUALLY
[linuxserver]$
```

```
    export PASSWORD='mypassword'

/usr/bin/expect -c '
    spawn perl perlscript.pl
    expect {
        -nocase "*assword*" {
            send "$env(PASSWORD)\r"
            exp_continue
        }
expect -c "
    expect "*assword*"
    send \$env(PASSWORD)\r
    interact"
    }

interact
'
```

Comment: Your indentation does not reflect the organization of the single `expect` statement in that. Pay close attention to the curly brackets and double quotes.

Comment: Take a look at my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write Expect scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use a quoted heredoc when putting an expect script inside a bash script, it reduces quoting hell significantly.

It seems you need to enter the passwords and then just wait for the perl program to end:

1. put multiple patterns in the same expect command
2. use the special `eof` pattern to expect the end of the spawned program.

```sh
/usr/bin/expect <<'END_EXPECT'
    set timeout -1
    spawn perl perlscript.pl
    expect {
        -nocase "*assword*" {
            send "$env(PASSWORD)\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        eof
    }
END_EXPECT
```

Comment: Perfect Glenn !! Thank you very much for your help !!